# Custom Code function not recognising value generated by expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a simple function for setting the Background Color of a cell based on integer values. It works correctly when I pass it a value from a field however when I try to pass it a value from an expression, it does not work.

```
    Public Function GetColor(ByVal Percentage As Double) As String
                Dim returnValue As String

    Select Case Percentage
       Case Is < 10     
       returnValue = "No Color" 
    Case Is < 20    
       returnValue  = "Orange"
    Case Is >= 20   
       returnValue = "Red"  
    End Select

    Return returnValue
End Function
```

The expression is:

```
=Code.GetColor((Fields!Total.Value/sum(Fields!Total.Value, "mainDataSetQuery")))
```

Where "mainDataSetQuery is a Dataset and not a Group.

This works but is obviously not what I want:

```
  =Code.GetColor(Fields!Total.Value)
```

Comment: What does your expression resolve to? Have you just put `=Fields!Total.Value/sum(Fields!Total.Value, "mainDataSetQuery")` into a placeholder and seen if that works?

Comment: Yes, the expression works and resolves correctly.

Comment: For troubleshooting, have you set the value of your cell to your full expression: `=Code.GetColor((Fields!Total.Value/sum(Fields!Total.Value, "mainDataSetQuery")))` I wonder if the problem is only happening for some of the color codes being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this expression:

=Code.GetColor((Fields!Total.Value/First(Fields!Total.Value, "mainDataSetQuery")))